# How to build a star-sized humanoid superorganism?

Tags: creature-design, science-fiction, xenobiology, genetic-engineering, far-future

**For whatever reason, humans in the far future want to build a star-scale humanoid creature**. This massive lifeform would completely envelop a star in its chest area, **turning the star into its "heart" with a sort of biological dyson sphere**. Its chest cavity would be photosynthetic, collecting the star's total energy output and distributing it throughout the organism's body, like a circulatory system that runs on the sun instead of breathed oxygen. **What unique challenges would a human shape present at this scale?**

**Obviously gravity is a big problem**. Is there any way it could overcome gravity and maintain its shape? It doesn't have to look exactly human, just adhere to the overall shape and be recognizable as humanoid. It's a bit handwavey, but maybe this organism could generate anti-gravitational waves to cancel out the extreme force trying to collapse it. Or could it be strong enough to counter gravity through sheer physical strength?

**The freezing vacuum of space is another obstacle**. Would a being of this scale be able to maintain an atmosphere around its body? I imagine the gases would quickly flow towards the center of the organism, so perhaps it could constantly output gases through "pores" around its extremities. The atmosphere would always be flowing from the outside of the body towards the center, where it could maybe be collected and transported back to the extremities again. Or is a sort of "atmosphere" the wrong approach? Maybe its "skin" could adapt to withstand the vacuum of space.

**Creating a biological structure that can handle the complete energy output of a star is a challenge in itself**. Are there some stars that would work better than others for powering these creatures? After learning the process for constructing such a large being, would it be possible to modify the process and create a similar creature that envelops the supermassive black hole at the center of the galaxy instead of a measly star?

Now that I've (hopefully) drawn you in, allow me to unveil my far-fetched premise... **Humanity is building these mega-lifeforms to pilot and use to fight invaders from the ever-approaching Andromeda galaxy.** This is basically a bio-mecha anime, but on an even larger scale. It has been discovered that the only way to combat these foes is to collect massive amounts of biological material into one unified form. Individual humans cannot hope to cooperate well enough while separated, so they seek to turn as much material from the galaxy as possible into unified bodies with superconsciousness. Massive crews of humans should be able to inhabit and "pilot" these creatures together, although the creatures will have minds of their own as well.

**Assume that human civilization has reached Kardashev Type III and has complete control over genetic engineering.** I imagine the superorganisms would be able to make changes to their genetic code at will, to adapt to the difficult challenges that will arise when battling Andromeda's forces. Since the premise itself is a bit absurd, I am open to more far-fetched solutions, but I'm also interested in the realistic challenges this goal poses. I realize this post is a bit all over the place, but I'd just love to discuss this with others since I think it's a fun and interesting idea. **Can we create star-sized humanoid lifeforms to fight aliens?**

Comment: Hello ! Welcome to WorldBuilding !    That's a *lot* of questions, you might want to familiarize with the basics in here, generally, it's a one-question-per-post kind of thing, perhaps one of our moderators can point you to the  'User Guide'

Comment: It’s a little broad, but that’s all good! This is my second day. My first question was really broad too. You can edit it if you want, but it might get taken down if you don’t. Have fun, and welcome to world building!

Comment: Ah thank you for that feedback. I'm aware it's a lot of info and pretty broad. I guess I was looking for more discussion as opposed to a QA type of thing. Maybe this is not the right site for this. Apologies.

Comment: Sorry to be negative, but I just can't force any suspension of disbelief on myself with anything I could think of. If nothing else, square-cube law will kill your thing. Anything moon-sized or larger (or even quite a bit smaller, actually) just needs to be spherical, otherwise it just collapses under its own weight, whatever the material... Huge organic spaceships, maybe. Star-level huge, nah, count me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too hot, not enough power.

Any energy that such a creature absorbs from a star has to eventually leave its body somehow, the path being star → energy transport infrastructure → metabolism → waste heat radiated through the surface. If the creature's radiating surface area is not much greater than that of a star (read: your "humanoid' is mostly chest cavity covered in skin), its skin will have to glow at roughly star-comparable temperatures, which likely can't be good for its internals. (Making it larger has obvious cost problems as well as energy-consumption ones; see point two.) Unless you stretch the definition of "biological material" to include graphene radiators and the like, I can't see a creature made of meat of that size withstanding its own metabolic heat. Your engineers will need **really good heat distribution systems and abiological skin**, I would think.

You propose that such a creature would be made by gathering organic matter from around the galaxy. If we take Earth as representative of metabolic rate, a human scaled by a factor of a billion in each dimension (and also inflated like a balloon to hold a star inside its mostly-chest-cavity body) will need roughly 8 x 10<sup>28</sup> watts when simply at rest, a few hundred times what a Sun-sized star will provide. A project of this kind will have to involve **enormously reduced metabolism** or create a **hollow architecture** entailing mostly skin and some support pylons to reduce the amount of required meat. The former option goes hand-in-hand with [RandySavage's comment](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/183816/62788) on nerve speed; these creatures will be operating far, *far* slower than humans for at least these two reasons.

Comment: Awesome points! Thanks. The greatly reduced metabolism and speed is definitely a problem. Even with a magically perfect metabolism where no energy is lost as excess heat, I had not considered that the full power of a star would not be enough.

Answer (score 5):

The only reason why an advanced civilization would do this would likely be for show, to scare lesser species when they hear about a solar system sized creature.

There would be no reason for a creature this big but for the same reason Iron man would make a giant mech just to show that he can but he knows his smaller suits are far more efficient and effective an advanced species may do the same.

With creatures that large the speed at which nerves can transmit information around the body will be too slow to control the whole body at once.

If you did want to create a creature that feed off the energy of the star and was mostly for show you could have a swarm of structures like a Dyson swarm, each with their own propulsion systems to keep them aligned and they could even be joined by cables to help create the humanoid shape.

Comment: Good point - definitely a very "showy" idea. Humanity at our current developmental phase would definitely be scared of something like this. I like the Dyson swarm idea. Breaking the creature up into smaller pieces makes it much more believable.

Answer (score 0):

Um why would anyone do this?

If I had the means, I wouldn't undertake such a project. It's a waste of resources in my mind. And i assure you that all this is my honest conclusion about this.

Frankly, the only reasons a civilization would do this is a display of power, albeit short lived as it'll be dismantled the second the display was over.

apart from that, if I was the leader of a K3 civilization to a type omega civilization, i would laugh the person who proposed this idea out of the room, and have him sent to a psychiatric hospital  for a month long Psychiatric evaluation. Maybe have mind correction procedures ordered done to him.